# Name parameter ignored in Facebook feed dialog

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I try opening a simple dialog from my iOS app to post something on a user's wall. However it seems the "name" parameter is completely ignored.

Here is the code, I use the Facebook SDK from Github, pulled the version yesterday.

```
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"This is the name",@"name",nil];
[facebook dialog:@"feed"
        andParams:params
      andDelegate:self];
```

The dialog shown only shows:

> "Post to your wall"
>   "Write something..."

the text box

> "via MyApp"

When actually posting the post is completely empty. Why is the "name" parameter completely ignored?

Comment: Yes, the name parameter is not currently being previewed in the dialog but when you do publish it, it will show up in the News Feed story. So it not being ignored when published.

Comment: That is strange behavior. BTW if you want me to accept your answer you should post it as answer and not as a comment to my question :)

Comment: Actually, I just checked and don't see the text anywhere on facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I've found the solution. It works if you do not pass a description, but pass a caption argument instead. Then the name appears, the caption text below, and the parsed link text below that

Answer (score 1):

For some background, the name parameter is attached to a link you attach to the post, see the properties description section https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/. So add a link parameter alongside the name.

As mentioned in a comment, even though the name parameter is not visible in the preview dialog it will be posted and show up on Facebook, providing you also provide a link parameter.

Comment: I do not see the name anywhere on facebook, and I provided a link parameter (which it seems to parse and copy part of the content in my facebook wall post)

Comment: Seems I've found the solution. It works if you do not pass a description, but pass a caption argument instead. Then the name appears, the caption text below, and the parsed link text below that